# $conn->WebSocket always return ["closing"]=> bool(false)

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

i'm trying to use Ratchet with laravel but when i do a var_dump to $conn->WebSocket in onOpen or in onMessage it always return me

> object(stdClass)#670 (1) { ["closing"]=> bool(false) }

this is the code i use

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use App;
use Auth;
use Config;
use Crypt;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;

class WebSocketController extends Controller implements MessageComponentInterface{
function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn){
$session = (new SessionManager(App::getInstance()))->driver();
var_dump($conn->WebSocket);
}

function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn){
}

function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e){
$conn->close();
}

function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg){
var_dump($conn->WebSocket);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you take the time to consider my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a simple library called [Woketo](https://github.com/Nekland/Woketo) for websocket in php

> composer require "nekland/woketo"

The simplest example to run a websocket server

### Your websocket server

```
use Your\Namespace\YourMessageHandler;
use Nekland\Woketo\Server\WebSocketServer;

$server = new WebSocketServer(1337);
$server->setMessageHandler(new YourMessageHandler(), '/path'); // accessible on ws://127.0.0.1:1337/path
$server->start();
```

### Your Handler class, here you can retrieve and send data from/to your client

```
 <?php
    // YourMessageHandler.php

    namespace Your\Namespace;

    use Nekland\Woketo\Core\AbstractConnection;
    use Nekland\Woketo\Message\TextMessageHandler;

    class YourMessageHandler extends TextMessageHandler
    {
        public function onConnection(AbstractConnection $connection)
        {
            // Doing something when the client is connected ?
            // This method is totally optional.
        }

        public function onMessage(string $data, AbstractConnection $connection)
        {
            // Print the message received from the connection
            var_dump($data);
            // Sending back the received data
            $connection->write($data);
        }
    }
```

Feel free to ask if you have a problem during the setup